# Secure local storage in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, local-storage

I'm using local storage to store some data of my website. 
I store each object that the site need. 
So on the client's browser, they can view those object(in chrome : Resource -> Local Storage).
What I want to do is, make those object unreadable in order to avoid the client(hacker) recognize the object structure of website.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no way you can prevent the client from reading data from localStorage. You can encrypt it but they can decrypt it. You cannot hide it on the client.

Comment: why do you want to hide that ??

Comment: @mikakun : One of my friend told me that, if the hacker understand our object well, so it made they're easy to hack :S

Comment: your javascript object is going to help hack your server ??? expand doesn't make sense

Comment: you better make some encryption algos and apply encryption decryption while reading the data.

Comment: @mikakun Hmm but the javascript object and the object in REST is actually the same :/

Comment: & what is there to hack ? bank account ??? you sound over paranoid

Comment: Go through this link : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/74155/how-secure-is-localstorage

Comment: @mikakun : Prevention is better than cute ;)

Comment: that's not prevention, prevention is to not have any sensible data in js code

Answer (score 2):

If you are worring about security then you should give client ONLY public data. There is no reliable way to hide something on client-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crypto-js` in order to encrypt the string into AES encryption pattern and then save it into localStorage.
[crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)

But Hacker can decode this also..Because your secret key will be inside your code..
So better option is,
1. send the string to server
2. then encode it
3. then send it back to client
4. and save it in localStorage..

Comment: so can't Clint implement it and decrypt the information?

Comment: yeah looks better now,

Comment: @VickyGonsalves : `1. send the string to server`, Did you mean, string of secret key?

Comment: no the actual string you want to encode....